# How to find RowID in Excel using c# in windows app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

Happy holidays.

Is it possible to do this in excel using c# in windows application.

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status = 'pass' WHERE  ExcelRowID = '5' ;
```

How do I update any cell of the excel sheet using the excel row Id which you can see on the left most side out side the first column.

Thanks

Comment: are you familiar with Microsoft.Interop ? do a google search as well there are plenty of examples..

Comment: You can use a connection string with Excel, but the row will depend on whether or not you have a header row and / or a specified a range. Other than that, if the data is organized, it works just like any database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string execPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
book = app.Workbooks.Open(execPath + @"\..\..\Book1.xls", 
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
```

In this example A1 refer to 1st row 1st column, and you can get the other columns as like this.

See the full example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/fasterexcelaccesstoc.aspx

Comment: Thanks Raj for the reply , I am looking into this. This still does not tell me how to access the rowId...is it even possible to do that ?